# Multiple NSTableViews on one View Controller

Tags: swift, nstableview

I want to have multiple NSTableViews on one ViewController. I have implemented the first TableView with the following code:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "MyCellView", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        tableView.registerNib(nib!, forIdentifier: "MyCellView")

        let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.view = self
    }
}

extension MainViewController: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate 
{
    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int 
    {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 25
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? 
    {
        let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("MyCellView", owner: self) as! MyCellView

        cell.itemName.stringValue = "row text"
        return cell
    }
}
```

This NSTableView is working fine but it is obviously tied closely with the view controller. What is the best way of adding a second NSTableView?

Comment: Set multiple table view's delegate property to this class and improve your logic in the delegate/datasource methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found out how to do this. This is a much nicer approach than putting the NSTableView in the main controller in my opinion.

Each table is defined with its own class:

```
import Cocoa

class Table1: NSTableView, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate
{

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
    {
        let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("MyCellView", owner: self)  as! MyCellView!

        cell.itemName.stringValue = "hello"
        cell.itemDescription.stringValue = "This is some more text"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Table 2 is the same, but can obviously have different data etc.

My tables were View Based so here is the cell view class definition:

```
import Cocoa

class MyCellView: NSTableCellView
{
     @IBOutlet weak var itemName: NSTextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var itemDescription: NSTextField!
}
```

Here is the View Controller method:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController
{

    var dataSource1 : Table1!
    var dataSource2 : Table2!

    @IBOutlet weak var table1: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var table2: NSTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource1 = Table1()
        table1.setDataSource(self.dataSource1)
        table1.setDelegate(self.dataSource1)

        self.dataSource2 = Table2()
        table2.setDataSource(self.dataSource2)
        table2.setDelegate(self.dataSource2)

        let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "MyCellView", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        table1.registerNib(nib!, forIdentifier: "MyCellView")
        table2.registerNib(nib!, forIdentifier: "MyCellView")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what do you mean with "best". The easiest is to just reason based on the tableView parameter in the callbacks, i.e.

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? 
{
    if(tableView == self.tableView1)
    {
    }
    else if(tableView == self.tableView2)
    {
    }
}
```

But I'd suggest to create separate classes to be used as datasources. That classes would implement UITableViewDataSource protocol. You create two instances of that class and tie your table views accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to make separate classes, but I've been unable to see how to point the datasource and delegates to anything other than the main ViewController. Must be missing something obvious.

Comment: @iphaaw you're trying to bind it via IB, right? If you stick to IB you'll have to add your datasources to your storyboard/nib, drag NSObject from the palette and change it's class (I recommend against that). But I'd suggest you to perform all this in code. i.e. in viewDidLoad (or where you need) init+alloc each datasource and then tableView1.dataSource = datasource1 and so on.

Comment: Hmmm... I seem to be struggling with this.

class MainViewController: NSViewController
{
    _at_IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    _at_IBOutlet weak var table2View: NSTableView!
    
    var dataSource : ProjectList!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = ProjectList()
        table2View.setDataSource(self.dataSource)
        table2View.setDelegate(self.dataSource)
    }
}